# simple jQuery addClass() doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to determine what page the user is currently on. a simple indicator in the form of adding unique style to the navigation link the user is currently viewing its context

here is my script, all selectors working fine, if statement also do the job, but the addClass() function does nothing.. here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    $("#links ul li a").each( function() {
        var href= $(this).attr("href");
        if (pathname.indexOf(href) >= 0){
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    } );
});
</script>


    <nav id="links">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a>About</a></li>
        <li><a>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

HTML :

got it to work ,this is my finaly code, is there a need for any improvments ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    var onDomain=true;
    $("#links ul li a").each( function() {
        var href= $(this).attr("href");
        if (href != undefined && pathname.indexOf(href) >= 0){
            $(this).addClass("active");
            onDomain=false;
        }
    });
    if (onDomain){
        $("#links ul li:first-child a").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: I created a test case with your script and it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign `href` to `a`;

```
<nav id="links">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Then try:

```
   var pathname = window.location.pathname;
   $("#links ul li a").each( function() {
        var href= $(this).attr("href");
        if (href.length && pathname.indexOf(href) >= 0){
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    });
```

If you can't change the HTML then try like following:

```
   var pathname = window.location.pathname;
   $("#links ul li a").each( function() {
        var href= $(this).attr("href");
        if (href != undefined && pathname.indexOf(href) >= 0){
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    });
```

Comment: that works lol, i don't see any difference from mine except the <href.length &&> part..

Answer (score 3):

It is probably that the active class should be applied to the li.. Assuming your logic is correct and the class should be applied to the li (hard to tell without the html and css):

```
if (pathname.indexOf(href) >= 0){
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: I intend to apply the class to the anchor .. i will add html and css to main post soon

Comment: I have updated the HTML code, css is not needed at the moment because the problem is that the class is not added in the html code whether it's defined

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle that adds the class to the anchor..http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/DHABK/

Comment: i have updated my final code and everything is now working great, is this code any good ? it works and all but is it what you call 'valid' ?

Comment: If your code works and there are no console errors then you are good to go!   If one of these answers addressed your question please mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 2):

```
var loc = ''+( $(location).attr('href').split('/').slice(-1) );
if( typeof loc !== 'undefined'){
    $("#links li").find("a[href='"+loc+"']").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
}else( typeof loc === 'undefined' ){
    $("#links li a:eq(0)").addClass("active"); // if you use 'home' as your first.
}
```

Comment: This is an improvement of your script, and if you have well defined your selector 'active' on your CSS this would work like a charm.

Comment: This doesn't seems to work for me either, i defined the 'active' class well (if a menually add class='active' i can see the changes)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Please don't make `typeof` look like a function (parentheses). [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is not a function, but a operator. Also, how on earth is the `else` block ever going to be reached? When `A is not B` or A is B`, there are no leftover options.

Comment: Thanks @RobW. Reedited. I created a demo on my PC with the code provided by the OP and it works well. The error might be lying somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get the question at all, but I'd go for something like :

```
$("#links ul li a").filter( function() {
    return window.location.pathname.indexOf(this.href) != -1;
}).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function() {
                  var url = window.location;
                    $('#nav a').filter(function() {
                        return this.href == url;
                    }).parents("li").addClass('active');

            });
</script>
```

it's work
use this script when you use external file for menu

like **index.php** inclide **menu.php** 
you must use this scritp tu detect url loaded and class menu change to active class.

Thank U thecodeparadox your code is work